# Where is the window switcher in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, compiz, keyboard, desktop-environments

I just installed the new ubuntu 12.10.  I also installed the Compiz Settings Manager because I like to customize the desktop a little bit.  I really like the window switcher that used to come with Compiz.  With this setting, you can customize a key-combination (I like to use the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and you can cycle through all the open windows that you have.  It is a cool 3D visualization and very useful.  I think it was called "Ring switcher" in my 12.04 installation.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality the same way that you used to. The only problem being that ubuntu already had super+tab functions reserved. So, either edit these super+tab functions in the unity plugin of ccsm or, just configure some other shortcut keys for the ring switcher.

Comment: Problem is the ring switcher doesn't even show up in the compiz settings

Comment: It does on mine. Snapshots. Try reinstalling the package compiz-plugins-main.

Comment: You have to install the extra plugins to get that. It doesn't come by default anymore. This is largely due to the fact that Unity enables certain ones to get its look and feel. Be warned, you'll have to deal with a bunch of conflict warnings to get the ring switcher working.